# MySQL - Syntax to incorporate more conditions after the GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which lists questions or blogs, or both.  Questions have answers, blogs do not.  They are in the same table and have the same structure (heading with details) with a TYPE designation of either 'blog' or 'question'.  The answer table is POSTS and uses question_id as the common field between the two tables.

The user interface allows the user to checkbox on questions, blogs, answered, unanswered, or enter a search parameter on the question text itself.

A typical type condition would be

```
$type_condition = " AND questions.type='question'";
$type_condition = " AND questions.type='blog'";
```

My problem is in the answer condition.  I can do:

```
$answer_condition = 'HAVING answers = "0"';//questions with no answers    
$answer_condition = 'HAVING answers > "0"';//questions with answers
$answer_condition = 'HAVING answers > "-1"';//questions with and without answers
```

But I only want the $answer_condition to apply to type = 'question' and ignore it for types = 'blog'.  This is not a problem if only blog, or only question are checkboxed.  But if both are checkboxed, it means the user wants to list both, and the answer/count conditions should only apply to the type=question, not type=blog.

I want to do something like this as an overall conditional:

```
AND (questions.type='blog' OR (questions.type='question' AND answers ".$answer_condition."))";
```

However, I know this syntax will not be accepted in the placement after GROUP BY, and the $answer_condition must be after GROUP BY.  The queries work except for the above logic I outlined.

The SQL:

```
"SELECT questions.*, count(posts.question_id) as answers
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN posts
ON questions.question_id = posts.question_id  
WHERE question LIKE '%".$search."%'
".$type_condition."
GROUP BY questions.question_id
".$answer_condition."
```

The count/answers field = 0 for type = blogs.

How can I achieve this through SQL?

Comment: Please learn to use proper `GROUP BY`.  `SELECT * GROUP BY` is won't even execute in most systems.

Comment: Your query is malformed. It probably works in MySQL 5.7.5 or older since it allowed the bad syntax by default then.

Comment: Is the questions.* syntax not allowed?  Works in MySQL 5.6.20.  How is it malformed?

Comment: When using GROUP BY, all of the fields in the SELECT list need to either be aggregated or be one of the fields that are being grouped.  This prevents MySQL from randomly selecting values for the other columns.  This behavior doesn't seem to affect this specific query, but is important to keep in mind, and avoid.

In newer versions of MySQL this query would not be allowed (unless the [ONLY FULL GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) setting is shut off, which preferably shouldn't be done).

Comment: Interesting that it works in my older MySQL.  I had originally used a subquery to calculate  the answer count as ANSWERS, but then realized that I could not use this new field in the way I'm describing above... unless there is a way to use it I don't know of.  Then used the count() to do this.  When grouped by posts.question_id, it would not catch the 0 count values, which I needed, so I then GROUPED BY the questions.question_id, which did include the 0 counts.  But now that you say it will not be accepted in the newer versions of MySQL, I'll have to rethink all of this again...

Comment: The only thing you'd have to do differently for this query to pass, is that all the columns from `questions` which are included in the SELECT list would need to be in the GROUP BY.  For example, if you select just questions.questions_id, then the GROUP BY can have just questions.questions_id.  If you include all the columns in `questions`, then the GROUP BY would need to include all the columns as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be solved by moving both the 'type' conditions as well as the 'answer' conditions to the HAVING clause of the query.  The options would be as follows:

- questions - `questions.type='question'`
- blogs - `questions.type='blog'`
- answered - `(questions.type='question' AND answers > 0)`
- unanswered - `(questions.type='question' AND answers = 0)`

If the user selects multiple checkboxes, they can be appended to each other with 'OR'.